# Como mostrar datos en un pop-up desde un archivo json

Tags: html, angularjs, json

hola tengo un archivo json corriendo en un servidor local con dos tablas clientes y bonos.el archivo json llamado clientes con llave primaria id lo tengo en una tabla. Estoy tratando que cuando le de click al id de la tabla clientes muestre en un pop-up los datos de ese cliente pero tomándolos de json bonos.

tengo algo asi

```
    <table class="table table-striped results" id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr id="trstyle">
                    <th>N° Bono</th>
                    <th>Cédula</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Saldo</th>
                    <th>Fecha creación</th>
                    <th>Fecha vencimiento</th>
                    <th>Usuario</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Motivo</th>
                    <th>Canal</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="warning no-result">
                    <td colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No result</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="trstyle" ng-repeat="x in todos">
                    <td id="thbono"><a ng-click="cargar(x)" ng-href={{"#pop1"}} id="open">{{x.id}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{x.cedula}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.cliente}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.valor}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.saldo}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.fechaCreacion}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.fechaVence}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.usuario}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.estado}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.motivo}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.canal}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <ul id="#links"></ul>
        <div id="pop1" class="pop-up" ng-controller="TodoCtrl2">
            <div class="popBox">
                <div class="popScroll">
                    <table class="table table-bordered results" id="table1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr id="trstyle"> 
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Número</th>
                                <th>Cédula</th>
                                <th>Cliente</th>
                                <th>Valor</th>
                                <th>Documento</th>
                                <th>Canal</th>
                                <th>Mensaje</th>
                                <th>Usuario</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>         
                            <tr id="trstyleque" ng-repeat="y in bonos">
                                <td>{{y.creationdate}}</td>
                                <td>{{y.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{y.document}}</td>
                                <td>{{y.client}}</td>               
                                <td>{{y.valor}}</td>
                                <td>{{y.canal}}</td>
                                <td>{{y.canal}}</td>
                                <td>{{y.motivo}}</td>
                                <td>{{y.usuario}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

en el js tengo algo asi.

```
//Consulta un archivo json para llenar la tabla
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('http://localhost:3000/clientes/')
 .then(function(res){
  $scope.todos = res.data;                
});

});


//Consulta un archivo json para llenar el pop-up
App.controller('TodoCtrl2', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.bonos=[];
 $http.get('http://localhost:3000/detalle_Bonos/')
 .then(function(res){
  $scope.bonos = res.data;                
});

$scope.cargar = function(bono){
  console.log(bono);
  $scope.bonos[0] = bono;
}
});
```

muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guau, faltan algunos datos como por ejemplo la estructura de tu json y lo más importante es en que se relaciona el primer json del segundo, me imagino que quieres cargar datos según el primer json, entonces deberías hacer un recorrido al segundo array y compararlo con el id que obtienes al hacer clic en clientes.

```
 <pre><td id="thbono"><a ng-click="cargar(x)" ng-href={{"#pop1"}} id="open">{{x.id}}</a></td></pre>
```

la funciona cargar deberia ser algo así:

```
<td id="thbono"><a ng-click="cargar(x.id)" ng-href={{"#pop1"}} id="open">{{x.id}}</a></td>
```

luego para obtener la información y que cargue en el modal o popup es:

```
   $scope.bono_detalle = [];   
   $scope.cargar = function(id_cliente){
      console.log(bono);
      for(i=0;i<$scope.bonos.length ; i++){
        if($scope.bonos[i].idCliente == id_cliente){
          $scope.bono_detalle.push($scope.bonos[i]);
        }
      } 
    }
```

por último en la parte donde quieres mostrar el bono, simplemente pondrías esto:

```
<tr id="trstyleque" ng-repeat="y in bono_detalle">
   <td>{{y.creationdate}}</td>
   <td>{{y.id}}</td>
   <td>{{y.document}}</td>
   <td>{{y.client}}</td>               
   <td>{{y.valor}}</td>
   <td>{{y.canal}}</td>
   <td>{{y.canal}}</td>
   <td>{{y.motivo}}</td>
   <td>{{y.usuario}}</td>
 </tr>
```

y listo, así mostramos el detalle a la persona, sería mucho mejor si mostraras una pedazo de tu json y pulir mas tu idea, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias funciono muchas.

Comment: **Excelente amigo me alegro mucho**

Answer (score 1):

{
  "clientes": [
    {
      "id": 12131409080,
      "cedula": "1040",
      "cliente": "Jhon Smith",
      "valor": "300000",
      "saldo": " 100000",
      "fechaCreacion": "01/09/2016",
      "fechaVence": "01/09/2016",
      "usuario": "Angela2",
      "estado": "activo",
      "motivo": "El sujeto compro 3 Tennis 2017 con tarjeta de miembro",
      "canal": "aplicacion1"
    }
  ],
  "detalle_Bonos": [
    {
      "id": 12131409080,
      "jwttoken": "HER48",
      "code": "1234",
      "amount": "1234",
      "creationdate": "01/09/2016",
      "expirationdate": "01/09/2016",
      "canal": "1",
      "status": "activo",
      "motive": "compro",
      "document": "1040",
      "msg": "mensage 1",
      "client": "Jhon Smith"
    }
  ]
}